# How to disable plane detection. Swift + ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I've seen plenty of tutorials and suggestions on plane detection but I haven't seen any on how to disable once enabled plane detection. I want to disable plane detection and detected planes after I put my nodes on them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At any point, you can reconfigure the ARKit Session. So, in swift,  you can do:

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration();
//...any other configurations
configuration.planeDetection = [] //empty array (as opposed to .horizontal .vertical) 
sceneview.session.run(configuration)
```

There's a good example of this running within the context of an app [here](https://github.com/Placenote/PlacenoteSDK-iOS/blob/master/PlacenoteSDKExample/ViewController.swift#L377) where you can turn on/off Plane detection in the UI

Comment: from that example code in the link, It seems that once you re set the ARWorldTrackingConfiguration, you need to remove all Nodes and ARAnchors too? mmmm what if we dont? will nodes stay where they are ?

Comment: You don't have to remove the nodes and ARAnchors. This just stops the detection and addition of new ARAnchors and Nodes with plane detection.

Comment: Can we not remove already detected planes and just stop plane detection. Above code removes all the detected planes as well.

Comment: Is there a way to disable plane detection and place nodes in 3d space relative to the camera? IE, not wait for a plane to be detected to load an item 30 feet away?